# Android: Proguard issue for InMobi new version 6.0.3

Tags: android, android-proguard, inmobi

I am trying to take proguard signed APK. It was working perfectly before add the dependency for InMobi

Am getting the warning as

```
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.

Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
     If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
     the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
```

No am using the dependency as
**" compile 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:6.0.3'"** .Before am using jar file for Inmobi.

When I am using the InMobi older version 5.0.4 ,that is jar file, that time proguard have no issue.

Issue only come when using InMobi new version 6.0.3

Am using proguard rule that given in the site

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.inmobi.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient{
   public *;
 }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info{
 public *;
 }

-keep class com.moat.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.moat.**<br>
```

Still am getting the issue

Comment: Does it say which are those 2 unresolved references? Try running the gradle task with more verbose logging if it does not say more than that in Android Studio and give us an update.

Answer (score 1):

The real error that `Proguard` throws is:

```
Warning:com.moat.analytics.mobile.inm.ay: can't find referenced class com.moat.analytics.mobile.inm.ay$com.moat.analytics.mobile.inm.bb
```

That means that the library .apk has been obfuscated and we don't really know what class is causing the problem, however we know, that `com.moat.analytics.mobile.inm` package is causing the problem.

Having this in mind and investigating the `Proguard` content carefully leads to the last line:

```
-dontwarn com.moat.**<br>
```

There should not be any `<br>` at the end. It causes this line to have incorrect syntax and `proguard` just ignores it. Remove `<br>` and everything will be correct and the project will compile.